# My Ruby on Rails application only works if the address contains the port

Tags: port, ruby-on-rails, application

I have a Ruby on Rails application that works ok on my notebook ( http://localhost:3000/ )

- I uploaded it on my hosting server,
- created with CPanel X an application, the URL is http://example.com:12007/
- created a rewrite from http://example.com/ to http://example.com:12007/,
- and started it.

If I write in my browser http://example.com:12007/ or http://www.example.com:12007/ all the pages work as expected. But if I write http://example.com/ or http://www.example.com/ the first page is displayed, but without any css or images (just like it wouldn't find them). I can see all the text (even the text from my MySQL database), but with no format. And if I click on any link, I get a error page like this:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /some_controller was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

**What should I do to make my website work without writing the port in the address bar?**

---

The content of my `/public_html/.htaccess` file is

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/127\.0\.0\.1\:12007%{REQUEST_URI}" [P,QSA,L]
```

which I guess was generated by CPanel Rewrites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you access the /some_controller resource directly if you point your browser to it? The same holds true for your CSS files.    Can you post a snippet of the HTML source that includes a the HREF's or the SRC's for your links/CSS?

Edit...

Now that I look at that rewrite rule, of course it doesn't work.

```
^/?$
```

That's only going to match a URL at /.  Change it to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:12007/$1 [P,QSA,L]
```

And it should tick. Note that the above will proxy *all* requests to Rails. You should probably host your media outside of Rails' control, but that's an exercise for the reader.

Comment: It really works! Thanks a lot! I didn't understand exactly what you said about my media. At the moment, all my files and images and everything are located in `/rails_apps/my_project/`. And in `/public_html` I have only `.htaccess`. What is the best-practice?